# Select one record from a nested sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nested

Help - I have puzzeled on this for some time and am going bats.
In this cutdown query I want to select a single Email address from a contacts list that may contain multiple contacts for that customer.

My problem is that it does not find the Contacts email if I specify TOP 1 
(showing NULL for CC.Email)

> Note: it returns two records with Contact emails if I specify TOP 5

I think the TOP 1 must be restricting the records to 1 before determining a match?

```
SELECT C.Code as Customer, C.Name as CustomerName, C. Email, CC.Email, IIF(CC.Email<>'',CC.Email,C.Email) as Email
 FROM [dr].[Customer] C 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select TOP 1 CustomerId, Email 
                   from dr.Contact CC 
                   INNER JOIN dr.ContactDocumentOption CDO 
                     on CDO.TransactionTypeId = 102 
                      AND CDO.ContactId = CC.ContactId 
                   Order by CC.ContactId) CC 
  on CC.CustomerId = C.CustomerId  
 WHERE C.Code = 'B82'
```

Comment: Kindly provide DBMS, sample data and expected data.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 - My Customers table has many Customers, including 'B82' and my Contacts table has 2 records for that customer.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve a line for each Customer, showing the first contact persons email, or the default company email if there are no contacts.

Comment: ok I hope Eralper answer would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit hard to understand your question, but i guess you have multiple rows of the same customer, but not every row has values in the email column, am I right?

For this you should try including `WHERE Email IS NOT NULL` in your SQL string, the part with `TOP 1` is good, but try to make the SQL statement return values only if it finds an email, using Email IS NOT NULL.

I hope I understood your question and that this helps you.

Comment: Yes - but I want to return Customer details even when there is no email. Some customers have no contact person, and some have more than one. Where there are contacts I want to use the first contacts email, and where there is no contact I want to use the Customers company default email.

Comment: Okay, then you could add something like `CASE WHEN Email NOT NULL THEN Email ELSE CompanyEmail END AS email`, change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to LEFT JOIN directly the second request instead of using a nested request? And then you take TOP 1 on the main request? 
It would be easier to help if you had a SQL fiddle.

Comment: You are correct as far as my simplified query is concerned.....but I actually want all Customers that meet another criteria, and TOP 1 on the main request would of course only give me one customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the data from Contacts with `[SQL Row_Number() function][1]` and additional Partition By clause as follows

Please note instead of TOP, I used Row_number function and used the result in WHERE clause with rn=1 for choosing the top 1

```
;with cte as (
select 
    c.Code as Customer, c.Name as CustomerName, c.Email CustomerEmail, cc.Email ContactEmail,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.CustomerId order by cc.Email desc)
from Customer c
left join Contact cc on c.CustomerId = cc.CustomerId
left join ContactDocumentOption o on o.TransactionTypeId = 102
                                 and o.ContactId = cc.ContactId
where c.Code = 'B82'
)
select Customer, CustomerName, ISNULL(ContactEmail,CustomerEmail) Email
from cte where rn = 1
```

ISNULL() function is a better way to compare two fields according to one of the field's nullable case

Output is as follows

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eralper - that appears to work.I havent used a couple of those concepts before

Comment: Damm - when I stop restricting it to one customer - testing shows that your solution returns an email from any of the customers contacts, when I have to include only the contacts where TransactionTypeId = 102 .... and if I change it to inner join ContactDocumentOption then of course I dont get all customers (only those with a Contact)

Comment: Hi, the joins should solve the issue as you have suggested